# VB.Net and access via a variable of an interface type

Tags: vb.net

How do I make the properties of a class available in an inheriting class, for a variable that is declared to be the type of one of the interfaces implemented by that class?

What I have done so far is to create an abstract class `MyAbstract` with the keyword MustInherit and in the inheriting class `MyInheritingClass` I have added inherits and then the name of the abstract class. Now this is all fine, but in my inheriting class, if I create an interface on that class `MyInterface` and use that interface elsewhere in my code, I have then found that I cannot see the properties from my abstract class, on the variable declared with that interface.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there something else that I need to do?

An example would be as follows:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyAbstract
    Private _myString as String
    Public Property CommonString as String
        Get
            Return _myString
        End Get
        Set (value as String)
            _myString = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class MyInheritingClass
    Inherits MyAbstract
    Implements MyInterface

    Sub MySub(myParameter As MyInterface)
        myParameter.CommonString = "abc" ' compiler error - CommonString is not a member of MyInterface.
    End Sub

    'Other properties and methods go here!'
End Class
```

So, this is what I am doing, but when I use `MyInterface`, I cannot see the properties of my Abstract Class!

Comment: A simplified example would be helpful to illustrate your problem

Comment: I assume you meant to put `Implements MyInterface` or `Implements IMyInheritingClass` rather than `Implements MyInheritingClass`.  A class cannot implement a class--it can only implement an interface.  And certainly a class cannot implement itself, of all things :)

Comment: Sorry, yes Implements MyInterface

Comment: This Q&A must be read carefully by anyone hoping to learn from it. The first sentence says ".. how to make the properties of that class available to the class that inherits from it." But that works without problem in VB, so if anyone is having trouble getting that to work, they are doing something wrong that is not discussed here. Based on Andy's comments under @StevenDoggart's answer, what he actually had was a variable declared as type `MyInterface`; therefore the title and first sentence of this question are misleading. I will attempt to make an appropriate edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless I've completely misunderstood your question, I'm not sure why you are confused by this behavior.  Not only is that how it should work, but that is also how it works in c#.  For instance:

```cs
class Program
{
    private abstract class MyAbstract
    {
        private string _myString;
        public string CommonString
        {
            get { return _myString; }
            set { _myString = value; }
        }
    }

    private interface MyInterface
    {
        string UncommonString { get; set; }
    }

    private class MyInheritedClass : MyAbstract, MyInterface
    {
        private string _uncommonString;
        public string UncommonString
        {
            get { return _uncommonString; }
            set { _uncommonString = value; }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyInterface test = new MyInheritedClass();
        string compile = test.UncommonString;
        string doesntCompile = test.CommonString;  // This line fails to compile
    }
}
```

When you access an object through any interface or base class, you will only ever have access to the members that are exposed by that interface or base class.  If you need to access a member of `MyAbstract`, you need to cast the object as either `MyAbstract` or `MyInheritedClass`.  This is true in both languages.

Comment: I hear you, but where I experienced this problem was when I was building a function in the model layer of my ASP.NET application (it is a MVC web app). In the function inteface I wrote Public Function SaveToDb(ByVal _detailsToSave as IMyInheritedInterface) As String. When I period the Interface to access the properties to then link them to the rest of code for passing to the Db, this is when I found I couldn't see the Abstract Properties, but when I changed to the actual class, and not use the Interface, I could see everything. This is my problem.

Comment: And you would have that problem in C# as well.  If you can access members which are not exposed by the interface, what's the point of the interface at all?  If `CommonString` is something which all `MyInterface` classes should implement, then add it to the interface.

Comment: Yep - I am starting to see this!

Comment: tl;dr - if you need access via the interface, then add the method or property to that interface's declaration!  If doing so won't work well (the feature is not sensible on other implementers of that interface), then your design likely needs refactoring. Worst case, you'll have to cast to the type which contains that feature.